# Disable Javascript from cross-domain file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html file which intends to load XHR html files.
Here is my code:

```
<div id='some-id'></div>
<div id='some-id-2'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#some-id').load('some-url');
</script>
```

My problem is the external html file contains some javascript code which is executed after embedding it. How can I prevent this problem? (The url is cross-domain and I do not have permission to the remote domain server)

Comment: use ajax and inject via $('#some-id')[0].innerHTML= instead of .html() (called internally by load)

Comment: @Samuel, does the content from `some-url` have a single top-level element? If that's the case, you can specify a selector matching that element after the URL and `load()` will strip the scripts.

Comment: Does loading the external file work at all (and if so, how are you working around SOP)? What's wrong with executing the scripts?

Comment: Hamidi, what do you mean by top-level element?

Comment: Bergi, all things went well. What I want to do is only to disable Javascript from remote source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might not be the best solution, but since you can't control the returning data -

You can load only some of the HTML, e.g. only the elements that interest you:

```
$('#some-id').load('http://www.some-url.com/index.html div#elementId');
```

Also, like [apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710446/apsillers) mentioned, you can **exclude** the script:

```
$('#some-id').load('http://www.some-url.com/index.html :not(script)');
```

Or, you could remove it at return level:

```
$.get('http://www.some-url.com/index.html', function(data) {
    $(data).find('script').remove();
    $('#some-id').html(data);
});
```

Comment: No use because the javascript code remote has been executed before setting this command.

Comment: If it doesn't get inserted into the DOM, it shouldn't be executed - try the `$.get` method

Comment: Still the same when I use get method.